# Why does the website redirects to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi when the account is already deleted?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, google-cloud-platform, cpanel

**Steps:**
The Wordpress website was using cPanel.
I have migrated the website to GCP.
Deleted the cPanel account and changed the DNS to GCP(not using cPanel).
I've checked the DNS and it is pointing correctly to the new server.

I've no idea why the website is redirected to example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi when the account is already deleted?

Where can I look into to fix this?

Comment: How long since you changed the DNS settings? It takes time for DNS changes to propagate (24 - 72 hours). Also, some browser cache - try a different browser.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. You are right. After 3 days it is finally fixed. I have not encountered DNS propagation takes more than a few hours to propagate.

Comment: How long depends on the TTL settings that you had on the DNS server resource record plus intermediate DNS servers might use their own time values.